# Deallocating memory from a vector of vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

I'm creating a particle physics simulator and I need to make proper memory management.

I've found convenient that my method propagates several particles at once so this method returns a vector of trajectories and each trajectory is a vector of Steps (thus getting a `vector< vector<> >`).

(Step is a class I created.)

```
vector< vector<Step*> > Propagator::Propagate (vector<TParticle*> vpart) {
  vector< vector<Step*> > = vvsteps;
  //vvsteps goes through physics and gets filled using push_back
  //all of vvsteps' entries were filled with objects created with "new"

  return vvsteps;
}
```

Each Step creates a vector of pointers to TParticle (created with new) and has the following destructor to deallocate it.

```
vector<TParticle*> vpart;

Step::~Step() {
  for(int i=0; i<vpart.size(); i++) delete vpart[i];
  vpart.clear();
}
```

After I get what I want I try to deallocate the whole thing by doing:

```
vector< vector<Step*> > vvstep = prop->Propagate(vpart);

/*PHYSICS GOES HERE*/

for(int i=0; i<vvstep.size(); i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<vvstep[i].size(); j++)
    delete (vvstep[i])[j];
  vvstep[i].clear();
}
vvstep.clear();
```

This code for some reason doesn't work. It gives me the following error

```
*** glibc detected *** bin/rtest.exe: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0f7207f0 ***
```

edit: corrected a typo, the class is named Step and not Steps.

Comment: Consider using smart pointers instead of performing manual memory management through raw pointers, `new`, and `delete`

Comment: Is `vector< vector<Steps*> > = vvsteps;` a typo?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code you have posted, but when working with pointers like this, it is easy to accidentally copy a vector of pointers, and then try to delete the copy as well as the original.  If you can post a self-contained example we might be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: If `Step` is a class you've defined, what is `Steps`? How much of this code is real?

Comment: Does the corruption happen in `step` destructor or the other `delete` statement?

Comment: And if you've got a C++11 compiler you can make your Setp and TParticle movable and use vector<TParticle> and vector< vector<Steps>> instead. It does not appear that your types are run-time polymorphic so there is no reason to store pointers.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This code I showed was in fact 100% correct. The problem was in the creation of the vector of vectors. By (my) bad programming, I, sometimes, made 2 push_back's of the same object so when it deleted entry n and went to delete n+1, the n+1 had already been deleted since it was the same object as in n. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your vector of vector type to:

```
`std::vector< std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Step>>>`
```

This does a few things.  First, it blocks copying your `std::vector`s around, which is bad because such vectors represent both ownership and reference to data.

`move` is still available, and should generally occur.  If you want to move one set of vectors of vectors to another spot, and it isn't happening automatically, insert a `std::move( src )`.

Second, when the `vector` of `vector` of data goes out of scope, the `unique_ptr` automatically cleans up the `Step` objects.

You may have to insert some `.get()` calls on the `unique_ptr<Base>` in cases where you are calling a function that takes a `Base*` directly.  But it should otherwise be mostly transparent.

Note that the double deletion is probably occuring because you have duplicated one of these `vector`s of `Base*` -- the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` will complain when you tried to do that...